# Kafka Rolling Update Inter Broker Listener

Tags: apache-kafka

When migrating from one `inter.broker.listener.name` to another broker by broker, what does happen to the inter broker communication during the time where the brokers in the cluster have a different `inter.broker.listener.name` configured?

Let's assume:

- Broker 1 & 2 use inter.broker.listener.name "internal"
- Broker 3 uses inter.broker.listener.name "external"

Will Broker 1 & 2 know how to connect to Broker 3 and vice versa / aka is a rolling update possible? If so how does it work (at a high level)?

Comment: Answer depends on the listeners value that sets up those names

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can you go into more detail? I'm not sure how to interpret this. The listener's values would be just two different ports with different security protocols and different DNS for the advertised listeners?

Comment: For example, if you were to expand the cluster over fault-tolerant envirommnets, like run a stretch Kafka cluster in the cloud over multiple network domains/datacenters, then if the address is unresolvable after changed, then the newer brokers will be unable to connect until the firewall/VPC rules are opened accordingly